# Unhandled Runtime Error (TypeError): state.cartItems is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend, mern

I went ahead according to Mern Stack tutorial and worked on the store settings, and when I finished the codes, I encountered the same error, of course, in the store/cartSlice.js parts, in the components part, in the productPage component, and in the index file .js I got a problem and I can't solve the error. Thank you for solving the error.

store/cartSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
};

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems.push(action.payload);
    },
    updateCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems = action.payload;
    },
    emptyCart(state, action) {
      state.cartItems = [];
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart, updateCart, emptyCart } = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

components/productPage/infos/index.js

```
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import Rating from "@mui/material/Rating";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/Link";
import { TbPlus, TbMinus } from "react-icons/tb";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { BsHandbagFill, BsHeart } from "react-icons/bs";
import Share from "./share";
import Accordian from "./Accordian";
import SimillarSwiper from "./SimillarSwiper";
import axios from "axios";
import DialogModal from "../../dialogModal";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart, updateCart } from "../../../store/cartSlice";
import { hideDialog, showDialog } from "../../../store/DialogSlice";
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
export default function Infos({ product, setActiveImg }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [size, setSize] = useState(router.query.size);
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState("");
  const { cart } = useSelector((state) => ({ ...state }));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(hideDialog());
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    setSize("");
    setQty(1);
  }, [router.query.style]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (qty > product.quantity) {
      setQty(product.quantity);
    }
  }, [router.query.size]);
  const addToCartHandler = async () => {
    if (!router.query.size) {
      setError("Please Select a size");
      return;
    }
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/product/${product._id}?style=${product.style}&size=${router.query.size}`
    );
    if (qty > data.quantity) {
      setError(
        "The Quantity you have choosed is more than in stock. Try and lower the Qty"
      );
    } else if (data.quantity < 1) {
      setError("This Product is out of stock.");
      return;
    } else {
      let _uid = `${data._id}_${product.style}_${router.query.size}`;
      let exist = cart.cartItems.find((p) => p._uid === _uid);
      if (exist) {
        let newCart = cart.cartItems.map((p) => {
          if (p._uid == exist._uid) {
            return { ...p, qty: qty };
          }
          return p;
        });
        dispatch(updateCart(newCart));
      } else {
        dispatch(
          addToCart({
            ...data,
            qty,
            size: data.size,
            _uid,
          })
        );
      }
    }
  };
```

store/index.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import cart from "./cartSlice";


const reducers = combineReducers({ cart });

const config = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const reducer = persistReducer(config, reducers);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export default store;
```

addToCartHandler in components/productPage/infos/index.js:

```
const addToCartHandler = async () => {
    if (!router.query.size) {
      setError("Please Select a size");
      return;
    }
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `/api/product/${product._id}?style=${product.style}&size=${router.query.size}`
    );
    if (qty > data.quantity) {
      setError(
        "The Quantity you have choosed is more than in stock. Try and lower the Qty"
      );
    } else if (data.quantity < 1) {
      setError("This Product is out of stock.");
      return;
    } else {
      let _uid = `${data._id}_${product.style}_${router.query.size}`;
      let exist = cart.cartItems.find((p) => p._uid === _uid);
      if (exist) {
        let newCart = cart.cartItems.map((p) => {
          if (p._uid == exist._uid) {
            return { ...p, qty: qty };
          }
          return p;
        });
        dispatch(updateCart(newCart));
      } else {
        dispatch(
          addToCart({
            ...data,
            qty,
            size: data.size,
            _uid,
          })
        );
      }
    }
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] to share how you've created/configured the Redux store and provide  it to the app? Side note/question: Why isn't the cart update logic in the slice reducer instead of the UI?

Comment: Well, it certainly appears that `state.cart` should be defined. What debugging has been done? Do you have the Redux-DevTools and browser extension installed so you can inspect the store contents? If you added a `console.log({ cart });` in the `Infos` component does it have the value you expect? Where is `addToCartHandler` called? How is the Redux `Provider` component used/rendered, and where/how is `Infos` rendered? Can you provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: When I add it to Infos it prints in console browser this:
Object { cart: "hello" }
​cart: "hello"

Comment: I don't know why it prints this hello in the output and I haven't put this hello anywhere

Comment: I put the code addToCartHandler  of this above in the question

Comment: Is `cart: "hello"` what is stored in state in the dev tools? Try deleting the "root" that is persisted into localStorage and reload the page so the app is starting from clean initial state.

Comment: I removed it and it gives me the same error again and I don't know what to do

Comment: I think you got your app state in a weird state with invalid values. Try to completely wipe out/reset any state and persisted state to ensure the app is starting from clean initial state. Make sure you have only one instance of the app running so any other instance doesn't accidentally persist the bad state. If the issue continues see if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.